# Mocking mail with Laravel 5.4 (dusk)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, browser-testing, laravel-dusk

I'm trying to test mails within browser tests in Laravel 5.4.

I have this code in a `InvitationTest` class inside a `browse` callback function:

```
\Mail::fake();

$browser->visit('projects')
    ->press('etc.')

\Mail::assertSent(InvitationMail::class, function ($mail) use ($project) {
    return $mail->invitation->project->id == $project->id;
});
```

I can see the mail was sent in logs:

> [2017-04-06 15:36:10] local.INFO: Invitation xxxx-yyyy-zzz-aa-bb started 
>   [2017-04-06 15:36:10] local.DEBUG: Message-ID: <xxx@yyy.dev>
>   Date: Thu, 06 Apr 2017 15:36:10 +0200
>   Subject: hello world :)

But running `php artisan dusk` I got:

> 1) Tests\Browser\InvitationTest::testCreateInvitation
> The expected [App\Mail\InvitationMail] mailable was not sent.
> Failed asserting that false is true.

Mail is queued but, in my `.env.dusk.local` I have set queue to sync (and mail to log):

```
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync
MAIL_DRIVER=log
```

So everything must be fine. Am I doing something wrong? Why dusk says the mail was not sent?

Important note: The mail is not directly send via Controller, but a delayed job is created and this job send the mail. The delayed job is sent in the past, so it may not have an impact. To be clear: a controller dispatches a job, then this job sends multiple mails.

Comment: https://hackernoon.com/asserting-jobs-in-queue-with-laravel-dusk-adb03654ca43

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, mocking does not work for Laravel Dusk. Though, two issue are open about this problem:

- https://github.com/laravel/dusk/issues/152
- https://github.com/laravel/dusk/issues/121

Answer (score 0):

Dusk runs in a separate process, so there is no way you can use Mail::fake() when doing Dusk tests. Actually it is like you are working with your app directly, simply with a test vars.

Here is a way you can test emails when doing Dusk tests by the way - https://medium.com/@naneri/how-to-test-laravel-dusk-emails-826e77c4d53d